# Reversing a way one linked list

Tags: c

I want to try a function makes reversing a linked list. A looked up for somecodes but i don't understand their's algorithms. Can anybody explain how this works (intherative solution) ? A tried somethings, but not worked.

current code:

```
void rvrprint(struct node *go)
{
    struct node *tmp;
    struct node *onc=NULL;

    struct node *snk;
    tmp=go;
    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        snk = tmp->next;
        tmp->next=onc;
        tmp=snk;
        printf("%d\n",tmp->x);
    }
    head = tmp;
}
```

Comment: You tried some things but it did not work. Well, what did you try and in what way did it not work?

Comment: You need to specify your data structure and you should also include your attempted solutions so others can point out what you need to change. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service where you come empty handed and leave with a full solution

Comment: yeah but i want to explain it's algorithm, didn't want to write my code.

Comment: @frogwine Take a look at this from everyone else' perspective: you are asking people to explain to you an algorithm that you don't understand. But you do not specify which algorithm (there are many ways to reverse a linked list), and you do not explain what you don't understand. You are not making it easy for people that would want to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at a single-link list as a stack. If you do then you should hopefully soon realize that the simplest way to reverse it is to take the first node and add it to a new list (*pushing* the node onto a new stack). Then take the second node and add to the new list (again pushing onto the new stack).

Already after this you should see that the order of the first two nodes are reversed. This will continue as you go through the whole original list, and "push" its nodes onto the new list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement this:

[image]

but as you you say your self: Your code isn't working!

Well, you have missed one important step inside the loop.

You should be able to find it by studying the drawing above while comparing with your code. If not, drop a comment :-)

BTW: This also looks wrong

```
head = tmp;
```

as `temp` is `NULL`.